# Filtering Pandas df by date and another column value

Tags: python, pandas

The df looks like this:

```
df.columns = ['ReportDate', 'ClientId', 'ClientRevenue']
```

I want to get list of all clients reporting higher revenue b/w 2 dates. Here's some non-tested, outline code but wondering if there's a more direct, Pythonic approach:

```
enddatedf = df.loc[df['ReportDate'] == endDate]
startdatedf = df.loc[df['ReportDate'] == startDate]

endclients = enddatedf['ClientId'].unique()
startclients = startdatedf['ClientId'].unique()
commonclients = list(set(startclients).intersect(set(endclients)) #because clients might have dropped off in b/w

risingclients = []
for client in commonclients:
    startrevenue = startdatedf.loc[startdatedf['ClientId'] == client, 'ClientRevenue'].values[0]
    endrevenue = enddatedf.loc[enddatedf['ClientId'] == client, 'ClientRevenue'].values[0]
    if endrevenue > startrevenue:
    risingclients.append(client)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you include a small sample of your dataframe besides just the column names?

Comment: Why call unique if you’re going to pass to set()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating data. Please provide data in your questions. :)

```
startdate = pd.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
enddate = pd.datetime(2019, 3, 31)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "ReportDate": [startdate, enddate, startdate, enddate, startdate, enddate],
        "ClientId": [2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2],
        "ClientRevenue": [1432, 8493, 2316, 2145, 3211, 8763],
    }
)

print(df)

  ReportDate  ClientId  ClientRevenue
0 2019-01-01         2           1432
1 2019-03-31         1           8493
2 2019-01-01         3           2316
3 2019-03-31         3           2145
4 2019-01-01         1           3211
5 2019-03-31         2           8763
```

First step is to filter the df for the startdate and enddate.

```
df = df.loc[((df['ReportDate']==startdate) | (df['ReportDate']==enddate)),:]
```

Next sort the dataframe so that you will have clients together, in date order.

```
df = df.sort_values(['ClientId','ReportDate'])

ReportDate  ClientId  ClientRevenue
4 2019-01-01         1           3211
1 2019-03-31         1           8493
0 2019-01-01         2           1432
5 2019-03-31         2           8763
2 2019-01-01         3           2316
3 2019-03-31         3           2145
```

Next, subtract the startdate ClientRevenue, from the enddate ClientRevenue. If the value is positive, then the client had growth between the two dates.

```
result = df.groupby('ClientId').last() - df.groupby('ClientId').first()
print(result)

         ReportDate  ClientRevenue
ClientId                          
1           89 days           5282
2           89 days           7331
3           89 days           -171
```

Finally, filter the result dataframe for positive 'ClientRevenue' and put the index ('ClientId') to list.

```
print("ClientId with positive return: ", result[result['ClientRevenue']>0].index.tolist())
ClientId with positive return:  [1, 2]
```

**EDIT**
I missed the part about clients dropping off, but I went back and tested and it still works.

Adding in ClientId = 0 but only with a startdate.

```
  ReportDate  ClientId  ClientRevenue
0 2019-01-01         0           1324
1 2019-01-01         2           1432
2 2019-03-31         1           8493
3 2019-01-01         3           2316
4 2019-03-31         3           2145
5 2019-01-01         1           3211
6 2019-03-31         2           8763
```

result calculation is:

```
         ReportDate  ClientRevenue
ClientId                          
0            0 days              0
1           89 days           5282
2           89 days           7331
3           89 days           -171

ClientId with positive return:  [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ReportDate'], ascending=[True]) #Ensure your ReportDate is datetime column
df = df[(df['ReportDate'] > startDate) & (df['date'] <= endDate)] #You can have startDate, endDate as variables at top of your code section
del df['ReportDate']
df = df.groupby(['ClientId'],as_index=False).sum()
df = df.sort_values(['ClientRevenue'], ascending=[False])
top5 = df.head(5)   #Selecting the top 5 clients
```